# HTML mail does not display complete on android gmail client

Tags: android, html, css, email, responsive-design

I am sending newsletter from my web application. I have a problem in designing the mail.

The gmail client displays only one half of the message (the right half here as the mail is in Arabic) as in the below image.

[image]

How can I make all the message appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email display space varies from one client to another. For example gmail allocates say 500px size for showing the email when viewed through pc and the rest of space for other tabs. So this display size varies a lot.

Solution:

Place your contents within a table. Create a parent table and set its width to 100% so it occupies the entire allocated space. Within that create another table and give it a size of 500px ( usually you can give a size of 400-600 but not more than that). Inside this second table you post your contents. To make it look good you "center" the table 2 within table 1.

This how an html email will look in Gmail Mobile App if you follow my concept

[image]

Comment: My newsletter design is complicated and I think there is a lot of mistakes that make this answer did not work with me. But, as a general rule your answer is perfect.